# Android: How to get certain values from JSON

Tags: java, android, json

I have the following code in my main activity.

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
jObj.getJSONObject("body");
```

The contents of jObj looks like this:

```
{
    "body" : {
        "name" : {
            "test" : "abc"
        }
    }
}
```

I can get the value of "body" by iterating "jObj.keys()", but how can I get the value of "name"?

Comment: jObj.getJSONObject("body").getJSONObject("name"); - try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
JSONObject objectName = jObj.getJSONObject("body").getJSONObject("name");
String test = objectName.getString("test"); //return abc
```

Answer (score 1):

Try  this..

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
JSONObject  js = jObj.getJSONObject("body");
JSONObject  jo = js.getJSONObject("name");
System.out.println("test value "+jo.getString("test");
```